# ng-click not firing $scope.doSomething(), onclick for same function works

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The controller I'm using is:

```
angular.module('app.PostView', [])

.controller('PostViewCtrl', function($scope, $http, Constants) {


    $scope.posts = [];      
    $scope.doSomething = function(){
        console.log("in doSomething");
    }

    $http.get(Constants.POST_URL)
        .then(function (response){
            console.log(response);

            var post = new PostFactory(response.data);

            $scope.posts.push(post);



        });


})
```

The view for the controller is

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts" >
  <div class="home-container">
    <div id="details-container">
          <!-- using single item Array instead of single iftem to fix linkify bug -->
        <div ng-bind="post.desc"></div>
        <span class="item-note single-post-details">
          <!-- <div class="time-text">{{post.id}}</div> -->
          <div class="title" >{{post.title}}</div>
        </span>
        <a ng-click="doSomething()" href="#" >{{post.name}}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I replace ng-click with onclick then doSomething is triggered. Currently it is not. The same Controller and html code in other controller/views does work.

Answer (score 0):

When you clicking on the anchor, it change the routing as `http://url/#`, that listen by the `$routeProvider` & `ng-view` loads the default view and template as you are seeing on your side.

Basically you need to remove `href="#"` from your anchor link or just put `href=""` blank in that anchor. That would fix your problem.

```
 <a ng-click="doSomething()" href="" >{{post.name}}</a>
```

Comment: That's not it. Tried removing it and it still doesn't work. Also, the same HTML and JS code with the href tag works in another controller.

Answer (score 0):

Remove href completely

```
<a ng-click="doSomething()" 
   style='cursor:pointer' >{{post.name}}</a>
```

Comment: Tried that, it still doesn't work, but using onclick it does. It makes me thing its something to do with the $scope binding